# How to add number of records in a grid from devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a desktop application with a grid control from devexpress.
I want to add a row with total number of rows in a grid on the last row of the grid.

Exemple:

```
ApplicationType 
A
B
C
D
No. records:4
```

In load form event I wrote :

```
MyGridControl.DataSource=....
MyGridView.Columns["ApplicationType"].SummaryItem.SetSummary(DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Count, "{0:n0} inregistrari");
```

But with this code doesn't do anything .Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display [total summary](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument699) you should also enable showing grid's footer. To display the footer, set the [GridOptionsView.ShowFooter](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowFootertopic) option to true.

```
gridView1.OptionsView.ShowFooter = true;
```